# Angular 4 - second http.get cancelled in prod but works locally

Tags: angular, iis

I'm having some issues with cancelled request in angular. When testing locally I have no issues, but as soon as I upload to production the second request in a chain of requests gets cancelled. I'm not sure why this happens. Any help would be appriciated.

I've tried forkJoin but that doesn't work since the first request sets a cookie that is used in the next request.

I did some logging on the api side and the login request runs and returns a value, the second request also runs but gets canceled, third never runs because of the previouse cancle.

The website reloads everytime this happens, seems like a infinite loop.

Component

```
this.webApi.login().subscribe(() => {
    this.webApi.fetchDataFromWebApi().subscribe(data => {
        //Do some logic with data
        this.myOtherService.getMoreData().subscribe(res => {
            //More logic.
        }, error => {
            alert("Something wrong");
        });
    }, error => {
        alert("Something wrong");
    });
}, error => {
    alert("unauthorized);
});
```

Service

```
public login(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl + "login", { widthCredentials: true })
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError()));
}
```

The other request look the same but use another url.

Comment: You should really dive more into RXJs and its operators. A subscribe inside a subscribe (inside a subscribe) is a big warning flag..

Comment: Yes sir, I will do that. Why is it a big warning flag, if I may ask?

Comment: Because if one of the outer subscriptions fires again, it will resubscribe the inner ones and you’ll end up with subscriptions firing multiple times..

Comment: So, I've figured out what's causing the second request to get cancelled. The first one seems to run correctly but reloads the page upon arrival. I have no clue why, this doesn't happen in my dev environment.